# How to test for difference between two GLMs (generalized linear model) in R?

Tags: multiple-regression, anova, generalized-linear-model, ancova, differences

What are appropriate tests for determining whether two GLMs are statistically significantly different? AIC and BIC is not an option because I am not trying to determine parsimony.

If it were regular linear models, one could use type-3 anova.
Running GLMs through anova does not yield any interpretable results because no p-value is produced.

Please advise.

Comment: Type 3 ANOVA is only for comparing nested models, so the question is inconsistent. If models are nested, you can use `anova()` to compare them.

Comment: @MichaelM Thank you. Edited my question. The point it, I want to determine whether the differences in coefficients between two models are significant.

Comment: `anova()` has an argument `test`, which you can set to "Chisq" or "F" or "LRT", amongst others.